# Is it possible to use an Android device as X11 server for a remote machine over SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, graphics

When my desktop computer is up, I can connect to it with my notebook, even over the internet (I've set up my router to forward SSH to my desktop computer). My desktop computer runs GNU/Linux (Ubuntu distro), so I can use it with X terminal. My notebook also runs Ubuntu. I just need `ssh -X desktop.ip.addr`, then I can launch any program on my desktop machine.

So, the question is: what's the way of **using Android as X-terminal over SSH**?

I don't want to use VNC or other stuff. I think there must be some good SSH apps for Android (I've read about ConnectBot), but I haven't find anything about X11 (maybe it's my fault).

Comment: Why aren't you interested in VNC?  There are good Android clients for VNC.

Comment: You don't find much about X11 on Android because Android does not use X11 display stack; the only advantage of using remote X11 over VNC is if the connecting machine also have X11 so it can use its own display stack instead of the server's.

Comment: Yep, I know that there's no "native support" for X11 on Android, and therefore there will be no such joyful experience like on GNU/Linux, where I can use the same display for programs running on different machines seamlessly. Even on a big tablet, X11 will be a separate App, I assume, as just if it were VNC.

Comment: I'm still not clued in: what's the argument against VNC? Is the OP being reasonable or am I missing something?

Comment: Technically, I think you're looking for an X _server_ that runs on your phone, not a _client_.  Phrasing it that way suggests why it's unlikely: X servers are big and complex, and (I assume) need direct access to hardware.  That suggests you're unlikely to find one.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for X server, that's the piece of software implements X terminal. It does not need to access the hardware directly, it just have to send/receive X11 protocol over IP. There're X server programs for Windows, where X server is implemented using Windows API, not the hardware. Also, there are computers, which are dedicated X terminals, so there is no (access to) underlying operating systems, you have to connect a host running software able to use X11 (Xlib, sess/win/desktop manager, X apps etc.).

Comment: [Tizen](http://tizen.org) ftw which aims to be a complete GNU/Linux from the ground up targetting smartphones - Maemo/Meego. But the alternative is to have a ARM variant of distro - such as Debian, Arch, Slack - yes there's work involved but that's an exercise for you :)

Answer (score 6):

Apparently X11 can be run on the G1 via some sort of Debian image and shell app; see [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=486247) for example.  I can't find any other ports of it.

I use [ConnectBot](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.connectbot) for "regular" SSH, I find it to be quite good.  Even edited and compiled code with it!

Answer (score 4):

I've stumbled upon an [X server for Android project](https://github.com/nwrkbiz/android-xserver) (now available [as an APK to intall from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/au.com.darkside.xdemo/) too):

> This project implements an X11 server for use with Android devices,
> written in Java. The X11 server runs within an Android View subclass,
> allowing it to be embedded in other applications.

But perhaps it's [a bit tricky](http://my20percent.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/android-x-server/#comment-187) to connect to it through X forwarding via SSH... you must figure it out.