# Connecting to X11 on linux

Tags: ssh, vnc

I used to connect with SSH to school server on iPad with [iSSH](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/issh-ssh-vnc-console/id287765826?mt=8), which can work as X11 server, and remotely work through SSH and X11 with iPad as a server.

I thought since it is easy with iPad, it will be easy with Android. But silly me! It is not, as I see.

In [this SE question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-device-as-x11-client-of-a-remote-machine-over-ss) and on other places, people are telling "don't use X11, just use VNC!". However, I can't see how can I remotely start x11vnc on a machine where I am not a root on.

The situation is as follows: I am NOT a root on the server machine. There is linux running on the server machine. I do NOT have physical access to the server. I can connect to the server through SSH.

When I log in to the server and I try to run `x11vnc` like this:

```
x11vnc -forever -shared -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -create
```

I got [this](http://pastebin.com/S9dwyNfe) scary looking error message after trying to connect with AndroidVNC application (the error is displayed on the server and the x11vnc immediately crashes). If I don't use the `-create` option, `x11vnc` shows [this scary message](http://pastebin.com/A4QWXEf2) and x11vnc crashes before even waiting for the client.

So. My question is quite easy. What should I do to connect to the linux machine and do something simmilar to what I did with iSSH and X forwarding?

edit: aha, it seems like in our school we use outdated X11vnc version, so that's why it breaks. Awesome. Well, I probably can't persuade the admin to actually update it, so I will need another way of remotely running graphic applications, if nothing like iSSH exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it's possible to just run `vncserver` on the client - and it "just works".