# Run X11 natively via Chroot in Android?

Tags: linux, graphics

Is it possible to run X11 natively in Android via Chroot ? Without any kind of VNC ?

Thanks.

Comment: Cf http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4426/13117 -- a question basically asking for the same solution.

Comment: I don't think it can be done, as a chrooted system is in some kind of jail, where it doesn't have access to your hardware (unless you mount the devices, probably). I always use Xnest for that purpose, but I doubt whether it's available for Android.

Answer (score 1):

So you are asking about a native [Android X server](http://my20percent.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/android-x-server/)? That's the only article on a native X11 I found so far. All others seem to work with VNC somehow.

Not sure how the current state of the linked project is, as I could find no additional information (yet).